# Can't add headers to POST

Tags: jxbrowser

I have a trouble with JxBrowser. I just want to send a POST request with MY headers. And I can't do it.
     browser.loadURL(new LoadURLParams("MY_URL","MY_DATA", "MY_HEADERS_HERE"));
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that your headers aren't sent to a web server and your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use specific format for your headers.

Please take a look at the following article for more details: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013103-loading-url-with-post